# Google App Engine can't find jdk after gcloud update

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have Google Cloud Platform v147 and Eclipse Neon3 deployed with JDK 1.8.121.

Everything works fine locally and [Deploy to App Engine Standard] is fine.

I updated Google Cloud to v167. Everything works fine locally but [Deploy to App Engine Standard] fails with: Process exited with error code 1

The logfile shows: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

I have:

1. JAVA_HOME pointing to the jdk location
2. %JAVA_HOME%\bin is the first entry on the environment path
3. The first two lines of eclipse.ini are:
   -vm
   C:\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe
4. I have combed stackoverflow to find any other thing to try

Question: What needs to be changed in the deploy cycle so GAE can find the jdk and [Deploy to App Engine Standard] will work again?

Comment: Solved: 

As well as all the above I followed this:

Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs. Make sure that you point to a JDK here and not JRE.

Comment: You should make this an answer...